Traefik loadbalancer is sequential not parallel
We have app running in Angular 17. Requests are done using HttpClient. Below you can see 2 attached images. Both from network devtools tab.
PROD:

DEV:

As you can see requests on development are done in parallel. Therefore app is much faster. However on production requests are done in sequentaill order.
We deploy in docker+compose. On our own servers. The dev picture is using just npm start without docker, so both angular and backend(NestJS) runs in DEV mode. However I also tried locally in docker containers(settings same as in production) and the result is also Parallel behaviour, so only in Produciton containers it behabes like this.
Has anybody encountered this issue who might have a clue what is going on?
Similar problem here:
https://community.traefik.io/t/http2-loadbalancing-to-http1-1/17082
So it might be some problem with loadbalancing http2 to http1
Any help appreciated!

check the DB or the backend for the maximum number of active connections, if only one connection is allowed, maybe you might be getting this issue!

@NarenMurali thanks for answer, I was thinking that too, max pool limit is unset, should be default 10 in mysl, however I will still check.

Do you have many long running requests? Maybe in another tab? HTTP/1 is limited by default to 6 parallel connections per origin.

@Evert you might be right we are working on it right now, thanks for your answer.
